# error with google maps, caused by meta data

Tags: android, api, google-maps, android-actionbar, metadata

i got an error while trying to make a tabbed layout withh google maps implemented in a tab

i received the following errors

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
```

i proceeded to get my api key from google and this is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.hp_user.dn_tab1">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<!--
 The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


</application>

</manifest>
```

and created a values xml for the api which is giving me an error stating ***"element string must be declared"***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string name="google_maps_key" translatable="false" templateMergeStrategy="preserve">
!AIzaSyBIR8JqMnTpCaul4oX1HzgcR-HoJVR85CA
</string>
```

this all originally started when i noticed the actionbar was depracted and attempted to change it to toolbar in main activity as this would of allowed it to run from the original error i was getting which was that an windowactionbar needed to stop being called

main activity xml file

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    />
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    app:tabTextColor="#d3d3d3"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="#ffffff"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="#ff00ff"

    />


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

main activity java class

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Toolbar Title");
    getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("Toolbar Subtitle");

    // Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter =
            new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), MainActivity.this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    // Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    // Iterate over all tabs and set the custom view
    for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
        TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
        tab.setCustomView(pagerAdapter.getTabView(i));
    }
}

class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Home", "Shouts", "Maps", };
    Context context;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabTitles.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new HomeFragment();
            case 1:
                return new ShoutsFragment();
            case 2:
                return new MapFragment();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // Generate title based on item position
        return tabTitles[position];
    }

    public View getTabView(int position) {
        View tab = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.mapfragment, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) tab.findViewById(R.id.map);
        tv.setText(tabTitles[position]);
        return tab;
    }

}
}
```

im now stuck as i am new to android and now no longer understand, what could be done to make it run and not crash from errors.

**Gradle**

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

   android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.hp_user.dn_tab1"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'

}
```

Comment: Try to put your `<string ...>` on the same line.

Comment: Do you have try to Rebuild your project too ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change :

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

by

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
               android:value="@string/google_maps_key"/>
```

Comment: Done nothing either and after the rebuild my manifest is giving an error in the manifest

Comment: About attributes any "android:"

Comment: You have an error on all the `android:` ? Can you show your `grable` ?

Comment: Okay there's an error only on "@string/google_maps_key" in the manifest

Comment: Where is your `@string/google_maps_key` ? Directory ? File ?

Comment: sorry i don't know where the directory or file is? and i've added my gradle

Comment: Your `@string/google_maps_key` is in `res/google_maps_api.xml` ? If you follow th tutorial, it's should be that

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start?hl=en#etape_1_telecharger_android_studio Him

Comment: read through it, it doesnt tell me where the google maps api xml should be i know i've got the wrong name for the xml file but is it supposed to be in resource?

Comment: Yes just here `res/values/here`

Comment: i done it thank you but now as before all android attributes in my manifest are saying they are not allowed there for instance _**android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">**_

Comment: Do you have update `Google Play Service` in your SDK ?

Comment: I have a question, when you have you first error, the IDE has open the Manifest ?

Comment: I'm confused I think I opened

Comment: We can see easily that, if you try to open that open you another AndroidManifest.xml and the other, the title of the windows say `debug/AndroidManifest.xml`. That say you change the wrong Manifest.

Comment: Yh you're right, just tried to run it and got the xml file error again and a new error stating  _**attempt to invoke virtual method 'Boolean Java.io.File.mkdir()'**_

Comment: It's a weird error, have you try to rebuild again ?

Answer (score 0):

**Check for both these points**

1. string tag for the API key should be enclosed inside resources tag i think.

2.Are you sure your key value is proper? Google map keys usually don't start with "!" mark.
You mentioned this as your key
!AIzaSyBIR8JqMnTpCaul4oX1HzgcR-HoJVR85CA

Try without the exclamation sign

Comment: You have right but you can see, in the log cat the API key is `your API key`

Comment: create a new xml in values directory and root tag for it should be resources. inside resources you can declare your string

Comment: Yes, but in the documentation of Google Maps API Android, that say `When the build is finished, Android Studio opens the google_maps_api.xml and the MapsActivity.java` where `google_maps_api.xml` contains the `google_maps_key`

Comment: ok so check if google_maps_api has the structure as I mentioned above and if you api key value is present there

Comment: The key is correct now and so is the resource tag I noticed that but the new errors are just weird @shubham